# std::ostream not formatting const char* correctly the first time it's used

Tags: c++, iostream

I've been writing a custom `std::streambuf` as part of a logging system. However, I'm having problems with the first piece of output from a stream not being formatted correctly.

Here's a reduced test-case that doesn't use any custom `streambuf` or `ostream` classes:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::streambuf *coutbuf = std::cout.rdbuf();
    std::ostream(coutbuf) << "test" << ": writing to cout using a separate ostream." << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling this using g++:

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 4.4.1-4ubuntu8) 4.4.1

$ g++ -o fail reduced-case.cpp

$ ./fail
0x400c80: writing to cout using a separate ostream.
```

Note that the first string literal ("test") is being formatted as a generic pointer (the address of the string is output in hex), while the second string literal is formatted correctly.

The only thing I can think of is that it's invalid to directly use a newly constructed `std::ostream` like that (ie, without putting it into a variable).  If this is the case, I'd very much like to know what exactly makes it invalid (I assume it's nothing to do with iostreams specifically, but rather order-of-evaluation or interactions with constructors or something).  If that's not the problem, then what is?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that you must not write to a temporary stream object. This:

```
std::ostream(coutbuf) << "blah";
```

doesn't work as expected, since the left-hand argument for `operator<<()` is an rvalue. However, all the operators overloaded as a free function take a non-const reference to a stream as their left-hand argument:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, ...);
```

Since rvalues do not bind to non-const references, they cannot be called.

I suspect that your std lib implementation implements `<<` for `const char*` as a free function and has thus to fall back to some `<<` that's a member of `std::ostream`. It seems in your implementation that's the one outputting any pointer as a `void*`.

Bottom line: Don't attempt to write to temporary stream objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a temporary stream object like this. Give a name to the temporary variable.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::streambuf *coutbuf = std::cout.rdbuf();
    std::ostream os(coutbuf);
    os << "test" << ": writing to cout using a separate ostream." << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```